# How to properly define and call original operator<<

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
    const int i;
    const int j;

public:
    A(int i_, int j_) : i(i_), j(j_) {}

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o) const {
       o << "i is " << i << ", j is " << j;
       return o;
    }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const A& a ) {
    o << "This is A: ";
    a.operator<<(o);

    return o;
}

int main() {
    A a(0,42);

    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It will generate the following output:

```
This is A: i is 0, j is 42
```

The output is correct but I don't like how I am calling A's original `operator<<`.

I am trying to figure out how to properly define that operator, so it could be called this way:

```
o << "This is A: " << (some magic)a;
```

instead of

```
o << "This is A: ";
a.operator<<(o);
```

I have tried various ways but either I get to ambiguity issues or getting an address of the `std::cout` and broken string. Notice that the result `std::ostream&` of `A::operator<<` is a remnant of my tests. In the example above it would suffice to use `void`.

Is it possible without creating an intermediate class B that derives from class A and defines its own operator<< (`class NiceOutputOfA : public A {...};`) ?

Comment: Time for `friend`s?

Comment: @Incomputable: Did that and I got ambiguity from the compiler.

Comment: I meant that there should be only one free `operator<<` that would be a friend of your class. I guess what you wanted is provide access to members for `operator<<`.

Comment: @Grzegorz please show how you did it

Comment: @KillzoneKid: I have put `class A` into a `namespace X`, changed `operator <<` to be `friend`, and then tried to use `X::A` outside. I was getting `error: ambiguous overload for 'operator<<'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binary operators defined in-class always have the class as the left-hand side operand. Which means you *cannot* implement stream insertion/extraction in-class.

Probably the most common way is to implement the operator as a `friend` defined inline in the class.

Another reasonably common way is to provide a named streaming function in the class, and an out-of-class streaming operator which calls that function. You almost did that, but named that function `operator <<`.

Comment: The named streaming function can be virtual, and the out-of-class `operator <<` only needs to be defined for the base class, and then derived classes will print correctly too.

Comment: That's what I was trying. As I explained to @KillzoneKid in my comments, I have put `class A` into `namespace X`, and used `friend operator <<`. That caused ambiguity generated by the compiler.

Comment: As per named streaming function - that would work but in my very peculiar case, I have a library that has `friend operator<<` for the object I am using.
I wanted to expand this in my code do display more information that the `operator <<` itself does. I could declare a function 'showInfo(const Object& o)` that would call `std::cout << o;` then display all the rest. But I wanted to create a new `operator <<` that I would call, and this operator would call the original Object's `operator<<`. The more I think about it the less convinced I am it can be done without external class.

Answer (score 0):

The closest resolution I came to is by creating an intermediate class:

```
class Decorate {
    const A& a;

public:
    Decorate(const A& a_) : a(a_) {}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const PrintA& pa) {
        o << "This is A: " << pa.a;
        return o;
    }
};
```

and having it printed this way:

```
int main() {
    A a(0,42);

    std::cout << Decorate(a) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I was looking for something prettier but based on Angew's answer I lost hope to have it done suing proper `operator<<` declaration.

Thanks for all your help!
Marking Angew's response as the answer.